# Error in creating secret: com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (400, InvalidParameter, false) stage must be one of CURRENT

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I am trying to create secret using oci java sdk using this: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/java-sdk-examples/2.8.0/vault/CreateSecretExample.java.html

But getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (400, InvalidParameter, false) stage must be one of CURRENT. (opc-request-id: C4EB9DB09DDA436C8726E9B94C07B503/C6F1D676C4B532C7A5F1CDB1B8FEC023/7AA6550199EE36E59BA85377FF136466)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseHelper.throwIfNotSuccessful(ResponseHelper.java:140)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:88)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:84)
    at com.oracle.bmc.vault.internal.http.CreateSecretConverter$1.apply(CreateSecretConverter.java:78)
    at com.oracle.bmc.vault.internal.http.CreateSecretConverter$1.apply(CreateSecretConverter.java:62)
    at com.oracle.bmc.vault.VaultsClient.lambda$null$6(VaultsClient.java:576)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:89)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:60)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:51)
    at com.oracle.bmc.vault.VaultsClient.lambda$createSecret$7(VaultsClient.java:568)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.doFunctionCall(BmcGenericRetrier.java:89)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.lambda$execute$0(BmcGenericRetrier.java:60)
    at com.oracle.bmc.waiter.GenericWaiter.execute(GenericWaiter.java:55)
    at com.oracle.bmc.retrier.BmcGenericRetrier.execute(BmcGenericRetrier.java:51)
    at com.oracle.bmc.vault.VaultsClient.createSecret(VaultsClient.java:562)
```

I tried with both stages: SecretContentDetails.Stage.Pending, SecretContentDetails.Stage.Current

But getting same error as above? any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

this question is a little old. Have you tried this with a more recent version of the OCI Java SDK? We released version 2.33.0 today. If you are still running into this problem with an updated version,

Comment: I tried with 2.39.0 version and it works fine. I had to change the sample values in the example as they resulted in another error: com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: Error returned by CreateSecret operation in Vaults service.(400, InvalidParameter, false) content has an invalid format